# I believe turtle_teleop_key.exe is infected with IDP.Generic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Galactic on Windows 10 yesterday following the instructions on https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html

Today my AVG anti-virus has quarantined turtle_teleop_key.exe, saying it is infected with IDP.Generic.  (I also think talker.exe has the same problem.)
However, I see various reports on-line about "false positive" detection of this virus by AVG.

My AVG installation reports that it is up-to-date, as is my Windows installation.  I have asked AVG to check the file, although I have not received an answer yet.

Is anyone able to check or confirm if this file is clean?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382053/i-believe-turtle_teleop_key.exe-is-infected-with-idp.generic/) by [ninjaCoda20](https://answers.ros.org/users/74851/ninjacoda20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While it's impossible to prove a negative (ie: absolutely prove there is no infection), this is the result of submitting `turtle_teleop_key.exe` to [Jotti's online scanner](https://virusscan.jotti.org/en-GB/filescanjob/xqxwoq1rqq):

[image: jotti's scanner result for turtle_teleop_key.exe]

Note: this doesn't include AVG, so if there would be a false positive, this wouldn't show it.

It does include 15 other virus scanners though, and those all don't find anything.

Again: that's not proof there is nothing there, but given the fact that AVG is known to falsely detect `IDP.Generic`, it does seem to suggest AVG might be wrong here.

That's for `turtle_teleop_key.exe` (SHA-256: `6C8112FEFF2FF52B7D4108A8C93B3182A033AF00CA76D82D8F1EE1F94467289D`) from `ros2-galactic-20210523-windows-release-amd64.zip` (SHA-256 hash `8BF94E384A74A091F60793404ECF2736E4B955E916FEBF4C9BF7CB9511FC8E8C`).

---

Edit: and here is the result for `demo_nodes_cpp/talker.exe`: [result](https://virusscan.jotti.org/en-GB/filescanjob/nfl2v2nwlc). In case it disappears: "found nothing".

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ninjaCoda20](https://answers.ros.org/users/74851/ninjacoda20/) on 2021-07-09**:
Many thanks for investigating that.  I will keep a note of that website for the future.  Sorry if I caused any alarm!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-09**:
No need to apologise for anything. It's actually really appreciated that you raise your concerns. If there was an infection, I'm sure we all would like to know about it.